# Unity3D - Selecting a specific instance of a prefab with GetComponent<>()

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, instantiation

I am trying to select a specific instance of a prefab (created in an object pool). I would then like to edit properties of child elements within this instance (eg text within the prefab). However I am having to work with someone else's code.

I see they use the following code to control the text of all instances of this prefab...

```
            UIWidget w = GetComponent<UIWidget>();
            UILabel lbl = w as UILabel;
            lbl.text = value;
```

I am trying to use similar code but to only target a specific  instance of the prefab. This means the instance is a gameobject of the untiy engine.

The game object (instance) I would like to edit is stored as follows;

```
GameObject fromPool = ObjectPool.instance.GetObjectForType("Launch Site", false);
```

Is there anyway I can access the text property of a particular instance of a prefab in this kind of way?

Thanks,
Liam

Comment: `fromPool.GetComponent<UIWidget>();` ??

Comment: @Programmer Hi if i do this the button doesnt seem to load into the world.

Comment: Do you have access to the specific instance? If not why not use 'name' of object or 'InstanceID' of object? and retrieve the specific object. You will need to specify one of those. Else you will need to keep reference of the object to compare it from the list. Once you get the reference it should be easy enough to change the text by doing GetComponent<>.

Comment: As programmer mentioned above code should work to get reference.

Comment: Ok thanks @killer_mech